# Get name of enum

Tags: c#, enums

Is there a way to get the name/definition/type of an enum as a string? I would like to use this value for logging purposes. I am currently using static text but if/when the enum is renamed then the output would no longer be correct.

Bonus question: what is the technical term for the name/definition/type of the enum?

Here is an example scenario.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}

var value = MyEnum.Bar;
var name = ???
var output = $"The enum is: {name}.{value}";
```

Expected result: **"The enum is: MyEnum.Bar"**

Current solution:

```
var output = $"The enum is: MyEnum.{value}";
```

Comment: You could use reflection: `var name = value.GetType().Name`

Comment: you can use `Enum.GetName()`

Comment: @styx No, that would not help here. The question is not about how to get an enumeration constant's name, but about how to get the enumeration type's name.

Comment: @styx 's answer is correct. `Enum.GetName(value)` returns the name of the value

Comment: @ikkentim The OP's `$"...{value}"` already returns the name of the value. Again, that isn't the question.

Comment: @ikkentim Actually `Enum.GetName(value)` returns a compile time error

Comment: would you mind to join this discussion and clarify your post a little

Comment: Ah sorry, then see Access Denied's answer. EDIT: Annddd his answer is gone.

Comment: @ikkentim The answer was deleted after a comment pointing out that for duplicate questions, it's better to just close the question as a duplicate. It's the accepted answer there, by Alireza. (Edit: and it's the same thing as what Fabjan put in a comment here.)

Comment: @Fabjan 's comment does what I am looking for.

Comment: @hvd, is there anything I should do to "close" the question or has it already been done?

Comment: @jhhwilliams It's already been closed, it's fine to leave it like this. (And despite the confusion it caused in the comments, I think it was a perfectly good question.)

Comment: @jhhwilliams if you think that one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, you can mark one of them as accepted. Beside this, happy coding :)

Answer (score 5):

that would be solveable by [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof):

```
var value = MyEnum.Bar;
var name = nameof(MyEnum);
var output = $"The enum is: {name}.{value}";
```

Ouput:

> `The enum is: MyEnum.Bar`

---

> I am currently using static text but if/when the enum is renamed then the output would no longer be correct.

Using `nameof(MyEnum)` will allow you to automatically rename this reference in VisualStudio, while a static string won't be catched by the automatism

Comment: While technically correct, I believe he wants to get it from `value` (which is why I think @Fabjan's comment fits better). Otherwise one could just as well write `name = "MyEnum";`

Comment: And quoting the OP: 'if/when the enum is renamed' this will lead to a compile time error...

Comment: `$"The enum is: {nameof(MyEnum)}.{nameof(MyEnum.Bar)}"`

Comment: this won't help if the enum type is not known at compile time.

Comment: `var value = MyEnum.Bar;` this would also lead to compile error. Unless you remane it in Visual Studio using the renaming function which will change every reference to `MyEnum`

Comment: @SelmanGenç: this was never requested

Comment: @Rafalon "Otherwise one could just as well write name = "MyEnum";" if you write it this way, the automatic renaming procedure in Visual Studio won't catch this string. But it will catch the reference `MyEnum` in `nameof(MyEnum)`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System;

public enum MyEnum
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var value = MyEnum.Bar;
        var name = value.GetType().Name;
        Console.WriteLine($"The enum is: {name}.{value}");
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> `The enum is: MyEnum.Bar`